# Convert .png image icon to .icns file (MacOS)

Tags: graphics, icon, sips

What command can I type in my BASH shell to convert a given icon in `png` format into the `icns` image format required by Apple `.app` directories?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306223/how-to-manually-create-icns-files-using-iconutil

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `sips` command.

First, store your icon as follows:

1. In an image file of size 1024 x 1024 pixels
2. In `png` format
3. In a file named `Icon1024.png`

Then execute the following commands

```
mkdir MyIcon.iconset
sips -z 16 16     Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_16x16.png
sips -z 32 32     Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_16x16@2x.png
sips -z 32 32     Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_32x32.png
sips -z 64 64     Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_32x32@2x.png
sips -z 128 128   Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_128x128.png
sips -z 256 256   Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_128x128@2x.png
sips -z 256 256   Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_256x256.png
sips -z 512 512   Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_256x256@2x.png
sips -z 512 512   Icon1024.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_512x512.png
cp Icon1024.png MyIcon.iconset/icon_512x512@2x.png
iconutil -c icns MyIcon.iconset
rm -R MyIcon.iconset
```

The result will be a file named `MyIcon.icns` that you can use to add to your `.app` directory.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306223/how-to-manually-create-icns-files-using-iconutil

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

`sips -s format icns icon.png -o icon.icns`

But please note that the image dimensions have to be multiple of 256, so you might also need to convert the original file to a supported dimension, e.g:

`sips -s format icns -z 1024 1024 icon.png -o icon.icns`